# Why is my JMeter XPath assertion failing?

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I'm trying to run a simple load test, but some of my XPath assertions are failing and I can't figure out why. Here is a sample of html:

```
<div class="g1260">
    <h1 class="top-head">
        <div id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl00">
    INVESTMENT CONSULTANTS
        </div>
    </h1>
</div>
```

and here is my XPath:

```
//div[@id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl00" and contains(text(),"INVESTMENT CONSULTANTS")]
```

The assertion fails, even though, when I look at the response in the results tree, the element is there.

[image: Jmeter response]

I have also tried the XPaths

```
//div[@class="g1260"]/h1[@class="top-head"]/div
```

which fails, and

```
//div[@class="g1260"]/h1[@class="top-head"]
```

which passes.

All of the above XPaths work ok in the developer console, but fail in JMeter. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you try with this expression `//div[@id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl00" and contains(normalize-space(text()), 'INVESTMENT CONSULTANTS')] `

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam yes, I tried that and the assertion still failed.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your issue, looking into [XPath Tester mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) of the [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree):

[image]

Also  your expression checks only for node presence, if you need to test whether text equals `INVESTMENT CONSULTANTS` you will need to amend your XPath expression to look like:

```
normalize-space(//div[@id="ctl00_mainContent_ctl00"]/text())='INVESTMENT CONSULTANTS'
```

[image: JMeter Xpath Tester 2]

Depending on the nature of your response you might (or might not) need to tick `Use Tidy` box, try the both options, if you are using Tidy - check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries.

If the above steps won't help - share your **full response** and assertion requirement and we'll try to come up with the most appropriate configuration.

In the meantime check out this [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using Tidy, and there is nothing in the jmeter.log file. I'm also using JMeter 2.11, so do not have the advanced XPath tester shown here. I amended my XPath to `normalize-space(//h1[@class="top-head"]/text())="INVESTMENT CONSULTANTS"` and it now works - I'm just checking the correct page is returned, so this is enough for me.

Comment: Good to know that you got it working. If you have to stick to JMeter 2.11 for any reason you can still use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to check the results of your XPath queries, however I would recommend upgrading to latest JMeter version ([JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) as of now) as new JMeter versions not only contain sexy new features, but also come with bug fixes and performance improvements so it is important to stay up-to-date

Comment: I did try version 3.2, but the environment I'm working on still has Java 1.7. As this is a quick project, I'll stick for now, but will upgrade for the next one!